# How to print a receipt directly without showing Print Preview?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

This is my code:

```
Dim reportHolding As New CrystalReport1
Dim myDa As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim myDs As New DataSet1

MYCOMMAND.CommandText = "select * from printDatasetView where receiptNumber = '" & 
Trim(receiptNumber_txt.Text) & "'"
MYCOMMAND.CommandType = CommandType.Text
myDa.SelectCommand = MYCOMMAND
myDa.Fill(myDs, "printDatasetView")
reportHolding.SetDataSource(myDs)
reportHolding.SetParameterValue("rno", Trim(receiptNumber_txt.Text))
salesReceipt.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportHolding
salesReceipt.ShowDialog()
```

I want to send the receipt directly to the printer without showing the print preview dialog. After the print let it close and go back to the form.

Comment: Did you try reportHolding.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 0, 0); ?

Answer (score 0):

You can comment out or delete the following two lines of code as they are only needed to view the report.

```
salesReceipt.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportHolding
salesReceipt.ShowDialog()
```

Then add the following code.

```
reportHolding.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
```

This will print to the default printer installed.  If you are not familiar with the ReportDocument.PrintToPrinter() method, it has 4 arguments.  **The first argument is an integer and is the number of copies, the second argument is a boolean to determine if the print job is collated, the last two arguments are both integers as well with the 3rd being the start page number to begin printing from, and the 4th is the end page number.**

If you need to control the printer used, you can use a PrintDialog class to get the printer name and then set the printer to use with the following line of code.  This line would be inserted before the line above that actually prints the report.

```
reportHolding.PrintOptions.PrinterName = <PrinterName>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. its working fine. i nee more help. how print over network printer too.

Comment: reportHolding.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0),  what does this 1 or false or 0,0 means?

Comment: I edited my answer and emboldened the text that will explain the 4 arguments used with the PrintToPrinter() method.  Printing to a network printer shouldn't be any different than a local printer.  Just make sure the network printer is installed using a TCP/IP port on any computer that will run the report.  If possible, setting it as the default printer will work.  If you can't set it as default, then install the printer on the computer where designed the report, then go into Page Setup and select the network printer using the drop down control in the Printer Options section.